# "No site configured at this address" when trying to visit Stack Overflow chat

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat

I am getting the below message : `No site configured at this address` when I am clicking on the `chat` link.

Can any one suggest me how to resolve that?

EDIT:

```
C:\Users >nslookup chat.stackoverflow.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    chat.stackoverflow.com
Address:  69.59.197.17
```

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the chat link in the header? Works for me.

Comment: @Yannis yes.you are right

Comment: What do you get when you type `nslookup chat.stackoverflow.com` into a console?

Comment: @balpha see the edit.

Comment: Thanks, that looks about right. Can you post a screenshot of what you see at http://chat.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @balpha given the screen shot

Comment: Apparently this is not a totally uncommon issue: https://www.google.com/search?q=No+site+configured+at+this+address -- have you tried things like hard refresh, clearing cookies & cache, etc.? And/or a different browser?

Comment: @balpha I'm able to load `chat.stackoverflow.com`, but `nslookup` is still returning `Server: UnKnown` for me (for what it's worth).

Comment: @Telthien That just means your DNS server doesn't have a name.

Comment: @balpha Aw, and here I was, thinking I had found something spectacular :(